# Let $H$ be the subgroup of $\Bbb Z^3$ generated by elements $(5,−4, 3), (7, 2, 3)$ and $(21, 8, 9)$. Classify the factor group $\Bbb Z^{3}/H$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quotient-group

I am studying for an abstract algebra exam and am working through practice problems provided by the professor.

The problem statement is:

Let $H$ be the subgroup of $\Bbb Z^{3}$ generated by elements $(5,−4, 3), (7, 2, 3)$ and
$(21, 8, 9)$. Classify the factor group $\Bbb Z^{3}/H$.

My general thought process is:

1. More generally represent the subgroup $H$.
2. Determine what the cosets look like
3. Determine what group the group of cosets is isomorphic to.
4. I noted that any element in $H$ can be written in the more general form $((5a+7b+21c), (-4a+2b+8c), (3a+3b+9c)) $ where $a,b,c \in\Bbb Z$.
5. I started to list out possible values for the first term to try and get an idea of what the cosets looked like. This quickly got out of hand as I realized just how many terms are in $H$. For example not only are all multiples of $5,7,21$ in $H$, Since $5+7 = 12$ all multiples of $12$ are in $H$. All multiples of $7-5=2$ are in $H$ etc.....
6. Clearly I can't start this part until I've figured out the first two.

My questions:

1. Have I understood the group $H$ correctly? As I type this I realize the problem statement never states what type of group this is. Was I incorrect to assume it was an additive group instead of a multiplicative group?
2. Assuming I am correct in assuming an additive group. How can I determine what my cosets look like?

Comment: By $\mathbb{Z}$ is intended the additive group, and you are right about $H$. But did your course not do problems like this? - there is a standard procedure to solve them.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Saying there is a standard procedure to solve these isn't helpful.

Comment: I think in 4. you've done a fine job representing $H.$ You should treat this like a linear algebra problem, but you're only allowed to use scalars from $\Bbb{Z}.$ So, are these three elements $\Bbb{Z}-$linearly independent? Once you know what is, and isn't a $\Bbb{Z}-$linear combination of these elements, you can then write $g + H,$ where $g\notin H.$

Comment: @Chickenmancer I disagree (about saying there is a standard method being unhelpful). I think learning the standard method of solving problems of this type, based on reducing the associated matrix to Smith Normal Form, is the only sensible way to proceed.

Comment: @DerekHolt you actually explained what you believe the standard method is, and for that I'm sure the OP will be grateful 

Comment: Thank you for your comments. To answer ancient mathematician, assuming the standard procedure you mention is the same one mentioned by Derek Holt then no my course has not covered this type of problem. As @Chickenmancer pointed out, explaining what the standard method was is helpful.  I found the method mentioned in a section of the textbook my professor did not cover or expect us to read.

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Comment: @Shaun Our class has been using Abstract Algebra (3rd Edition) by David S. Dummit  and Richard M. Foote. I found the reference to Smith Normal Form in Chapter 12.  My class covered most (but not all) of chapters 1-8 and chapter 13

Comment: Thank you, @Katie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subgroup $H$ is generated by  $b_1=(5,−4,3),b_2=(7,2,3)$ and $b_3=(21,8,9)$. So it is generated by $b_1, b_4=b_2-b_1=(2,6,0), b_5=b_3-3b_2=(0,2,0)$. So it is generated by $b_6=b_1+2b_5=(5,0,3),
b_7=b_4-3b_5=(2,0,0), b_5$. So it is generated by $b_8=b_6-2b_7=(1,0,3), b_7,b_5$. So it is generated by $b_8, b_9=b_7-2b_8=(0,0,-6), b_5$. Choose a new basis of $\Bbb Z^3$, $\{f_1=b_8, f_2=e_2, f_3=e_3\}$ where as usual $e_2=(0,1,0), e_3=(0,0,1)$. In the basis $\{f_1,f_2,f_3\}$, the last generating set of $H$ is $\{f_1,2f_2, -6f_3\}$. Therefore the group $\Bbb Z^3/H$ is the direct product of the cyclic group of order $2$ and the cyclic group of order $6$.